# Genotype in genetic algorithms

Tags: genetic-algorithm

What is the basic difference between `Chromosome` and `Genotype` in the discussion of Genetic Algorithms?

My guess is, Genotype is a particular arrangement of a chromosome.

What do you say?

Answer (score 0):

In Genetic Algorithms unlike biology, genome and chromosome are equivalent. Both refer to the way the genes are arranged in an individual to propose a possible solution to resolve the problem. I.e. both are equal to genotype: "The complete heritable genetic identity"  [as noted here](http://pged.org/what-is-genotype-what-is-phenotype/).